# Javascript: Change Global Variables but in a function without using "Promise"

Tags: javascript, variables, promise

there my question is: How can I edit the variable "token" globally? I want to reuse the new value of that var, defined in that function. I know that it is not possible that easily, but are there ways to adapt that, so i can reuse the new value?

I now know, that I can't really change that, but if I am reusing the "token" for example:

```
   console.log(token);
```

The return is "variable is undefined", but I am defining that at the top.

My code is the following:

```
//libary:
var Particle = require('particle-api-js');
//neues Objekt:
var particle = new Particle();
//username, psw. etc definieren:
var userName = 'email.adress';
var passWord = 'passssword';
//Scriptvariablen:
var token;

//Funktionen:
function logontoparticle(){
        var test = particle.login({username: userName, password: passWord});
        test.then(
        function (data) {
                token = data.body.access_token;
                console.log('Logged In: with', token);
                },
        function (err) {
                console.log('LoggingIn Feeehlgeschalgen', err);
                }
);
}

logontoparticle();
console.log("at end", token);
```

At the end I get the return:

```
"at end undefined"
"token1234567891010201239" (e.g.)
```

I don't want to use: mockLogin and Promise... I want to avoid that... Thanks!

Comment: But you *should* use a promise. In fact, you already *do* use a promise - utilise it!

Comment: And also you should not use global variables. Why would you want to?

Comment: Inside your promise return your token is not getting set as you expect.  Check f12 for errors and try to use that to debug your function as well.

Comment: @slee423 how is he going to do that if the `test` is async?

Answer (score 3):

Your `logontoparticle` function executes asynchronous code, which means that you don't know when it is going to finish, also, because of closures, your `token` variable is indeed being written, the issue is that you are printing before the asynchronous code runs.

You could try something like:

```
var token;

//Funktionen:
function logontoparticle() {
  var test = particle.login({ username: userName, password: passWord });
  return test.then(
    function(data) {
      token = data.body.access_token;
      console.log("Logged In: with", token);
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("LoggingIn Feeehlgeschalgen", err);
    }
  );
}

logontoparticle().then(function() {
  console.log("at end", token);
});
```

p.s. I hope you pass, also you should take a look into the following topics:

- Promises
- Pure functions